# Adding content to quick documentation in CLion

Tags: c, ide, doxygen, clion, manpage

I am using CLion as my IDE right now while developing in C. The quick documentation is great for showing man pages for functions. The issue I am running into is if I create a macro to a function I no longer get the quick documentation to the man pages. Example would be:

```
#define MY_SOCKET(x, y, z) socket(x,y,z)
```

Now when I hover over `MY_SOCKET` I see the macro and replacement. Is it possible to also include the man page documentation to `socket()`? Clion is using Doxygen but I cannot find anything. Not sure if it exists or if some work arounds are possible